# Connecting Actionscript 3.0 with a C++ backend?

Tags: c++, actionscript, frontend, backend, scaleform

I am curious to know if there is a way of connecting a flash front-end to a C++ driven backend? I'm not currently working on a project that involves this, but I found out about an application used in the gaming industry, called [Scaleform](http://www.scaleform.com/), that requires knowledge on doing such things in order to create menus in games.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to resolve the problem would be to create webservices using C++ and consume them on the flash side. It is a more naive approach and certainly not as good as Scaleform but it is certainly simpler to implement.

You could also have a look at [FluorineFx](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) which is an implementation of Flex/Flash Remoting services for the .NET framework. The project is open-source so it could help you get  started. Basically, FluorinexFx catches the remote calls in [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) from the flash player and pipes it through the corresponding .NET method and corresponding arguments. It also helps you convert back to flash native .Net objects such as ArrayList, DataTable and even lists of typed objects.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting, Ill take a look into this as well. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Scaleform implement their own custom Flash Player, thats probably not what you had in mind.

What you can do in a reasonable amount of time is pretending to Adobes flash player that you are a [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI)-compatible browser - see e.g. [here](http://code.google.com/p/screenweaver-hx/source/browse/trunk/src/np_host.c) how [screenweaver-hx](http://code.google.com/p/screenweaver-hx/) does it.

Comment: Ah. So basically, Scaleform developed their own Flash Player which allows that sort of connection to be built. 

What you recommended is something I will definitely take a look at, I'm very interested in using these language. Thanks!

Comment: Its definitely a performant, portable and flexible solution. You could look into embedding the ActiveX-control too if you only care about windows, but embedding via the NPAPI is in my opinion simpler.